# How to send response to a Command in CQRS?

Tags: cqrs, akka-persistence

I'm implementing a CQRS system with Akka persistence and I'm trying to understand the request response bit of CQRS.

There are few answers on SO on how to send response back to client and [this article](http://jensrantil.github.io/cqrsevent-sourcing-messaging-patterns.html#asynchronicity-and-feedback-loops) also mentions a few good patterns. But instead of generalising using big words can someone please explain how should I send response back to the client in CQRS for the following simple use case.

**Use case**

Suppose the user is on a page which displays users profile which displays the following information

1. Username
2. Address
3. Phone number

And In my system I have one Actor per User which stores that user's profile information.

On the UI user wants to update the address and the following things happen:

1. User makes an AJAX REST call to update address of user
2. `UpdateUserAddressCommand(address:String)` generated
3. `UpdateUserAddressEvent(address:String)` generated
4. `UserAddressUpdatedEvent(updatedAddress:String)` generated (state of the UserActor updated)

Now how do I send back the full state of UserProfile in the system ? Since CQRS discourages sending response for a Command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to the CQRS pattern, the REST layer can be considered a client of the system using CQRS, and therefore you may send a response (from the REST server to the web browser) without violating a "principle".

In your case, it's quite simple:

1. REST call to `/api/endpoint/1234` -> REST server generates the command as above.
2. Server returns code "202 Accepted" and sets the `Location:` header to
   something like `/api/user/profile/1234`
3. Client queries `/api/user/profile/1234` to query the full state of the `UserProfile`.

You can combine 3. with HTTP long polling if you are using asynchronous query side updates/eventual consistency.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks :) What about error messages ? Do they also get handled this way or sending errors like "address not valid" in the Command itself is also against CQRS pattern ?

Comment: A general rule of thumb is to avoid any errors in command handlers. In case of input errors such as "address not valid" the client (REST layer) can do premature validation to avoid errors in the command handler.   In case there are business errors (such as duplicate addresses/users etc) that cannot be caught by simple validation, compensating actions should be implemented instead. If they occur rarely, it might even make sense to do the compensation/fixing manually.

Comment: If performance isn't a critical issue, why not have the command handler reply to the client? A timeout could be used to fall back to the "202 Accepted" state, as a special case for if, say, high load prevents the whole loop from being validated in a reasonable amount of time. Otherwise, it seems like the domain model will really blow up, if you have to consider a bunch of persistent error states that have to be later rectified. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "compensating actions".